# Is it possible to adjust the size of the on screen prompts?

Tags: broken-sword

In the game "Broken Sword", which is in this week's Android Humble Bundle has a variety of on screen prompts which appear very small on screen;

[image]

Note that the way the text appears within the Arqade layout is *still* larger than what I see on my phone screen. I am using a HTC One and have taken screenshots, but due to the differences in screen size between my phone and my PC the text is clearly visible on PC.

Is it possible to adjust the size of the on screen prompts without having to screenshot every screen in order to read it on my PC?